# Ninja Form Text Fields are Popping Out on mobile

Tags: javascript, wordpress, input, form-fields, ninja-forms

I have added a contact form using the Ninja Forms Wordpress plugin.

It works great in Desktop, but not so much on iPhone/Android phone(and probably all other mobile devices)! If I tap an input/text/textarea field it does focus and brings up the keyboard, but doesn't show my input and stays empty. My Select/Dropdown fields are working fine.

Troubleshooted a lot but can't figure out what the problem is!

TIA

Answer (score 0):

I got my issue solved, it was because of a JQuery Function that was being called on mobile design.

So if any of you guys have this type of problem make sure Ninja Form's Form elements should not be disturbed with other JS function. If you do some JS function for Ninja Forms please test those in different Screen/device Carefully.

Happy Coding.